# Some files are skipped during batch cropping of 40K image directory in Python & OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, crop

I created a small script that crops 1920x1080 images into a 400 x 400 image from the center. Overall it works fantastically on a set of 100 images but when I try to apply it to my 40K images in my directory it skips a bunch of images. Noticeably it will start skipping hundreds of frames towards the later images.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import cv2
import glob

images = glob.glob("*.jpg")

for i in images:
    img = cv2.imread(i,1)

    path = '/home/moocows/PycharmProjects/Aim/croptest/'
    crop_img = img[(540-200):(540+200), (960-200):(960+200)]

    cv2.imwrite(str(path) + i, crop_img)
```

I'm starting to wonder if the issue is from glob but I'm not too sure, I'm quite new to programming for forgive me if things are a bit messy.

Comment: First step would be actually testing whether `cv2.imread` actually succeeds to read the image, and produce a meaningful error message when it doesn't. | Also, why are you "destroying all windows" on every iteration? You don't create any windows anywhere, so what's the point?

Comment: oops sorry, I had originally had a .show before.

Comment: Maybe try to read and write the images with the package `skimage` (`scipy-image`). Change one function at a time and see if the trouble comes from OpenCV (if you see the same happening with Skimage) or not. The problem I find with OpenCV is that the documentation for Python is almost non-existing...

Comment: @Moocows BTW, is this a 32bit python or a 64bit one? And add the test for failed `imread`, see what it does, and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @DanMašek  Hi, Thanks for responding. I'm using the 64 bit one. How do I test imread? I'm fairly new to programming so I might be missing some prior knowledge. I assume I just do imread and use .show, just to make sure it reads everything I have?

Comment: @Moocows When `imread` fails, it returns `None`. So, after the call to imread, simply do `if not img:` and then handle it somehow -- for example print some error message and exit.

Comment: Just to be Pytonic the preferred way is to ask `if img is None` or `if img is not None` as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: Start by using `print len(images)` and make sure it is the same as the number of files you expect your code to find. Then remove all the processing from your for loop apart from opening the file, make the loop print the filename and whether the file opened. Chances are some of those files are corrupted and won't open as images.